# Juego de dados en c++ sintaxis

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy realizando un juego de dados lo mas compacto posible dentro de main y me quedo de la siguiente manera, quisiera saber si podría comprimirlo un poco mas, o habría la forma de hacer un código mas sencillo, no se si me estoy complicando mucho y estoy usando recursos que no debería, el programa funciona pero me gustaría optimizar mi modo de programar, muchísimas gracias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int dado1,dado2;
string lanzar;



int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout<<"--- Juego de dados, se gana con los numeros 4 , 6 , 8 y se pierden con los numeros 2 y 12 ---"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Presione cualquier tecla para lanzar los dados: "<<endl;
        cin>>lanzar;
        system ("cls");
        for (int i=0;i<=1;i++)
        {
            srand (time (0));
            dado1=rand()%(6)+1;
            dado2=rand()%(6)+1; 
        }
        cout<<"Dado 1 ["<<dado1<<"]";
        cout<<" Dado 2 ["<<dado2<<"]"<<endl;
        cout<<"La suma de los dados es: ["<<dado1+dado2<<"]"<<endl;
        if (dado1+dado2 == 4 or dado1+dado2 == 6 or dado1+dado2 == 8)
        {
            cout<<"\n°°° El jugador gana, la casa pierde °°°"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        if (dado1+dado2 == 2 or dado1+dado2 == 12)
        {
            cout<<"\n*** La casa gana, el jugador pierde ***"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        cout<<"\n--- Vuelve a lanzar ---"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        system ("cls");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0;i<=1;i++)
{
    srand (time (0));
    dado1=rand()%(6)+1;
    dado2=rand()%(6)+1; 
}
```

Aquí estás simulando 4 tiradas (el bucle itera dos veces) y sin embargo únicamente te estás quedando con el resultado de la segunda iteración. Tu juego únicamente necesita una iteración, luego el bucle es totalmente innecesario. Por otro lado es preferible no usar variables globales:

```
srand (time (0));
int dado1 = rand()%(6)+1;
int dado2 = rand()%(6)+1;
```

Adicionalmente, fíjate que estás inicializando la semilla de los números aleatorios dos veces... con hacerlo una única vez es suficiente (asumiendo que el bucle siguiese existiendo):

```
srand (time (0));

for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    dado1+=rand()%(6)+1;
    dado2+=rand()%(6)+1; 
}
```

No solo es suficiente inicializar `rand` una sola vez... es que `time()` tiene una precisión de segundos... luego si haces dos llamadas a `time()` dentro del mismo segundo... ¡¡obtendrás el mismo resultado!! y esto tiene como consecuencia que `dado1` y `dado2` **siempre** serán números pares ... este efecto se produce porque los números aleatorios que genera `rand` no son para nada aleatorios... a una misma semilla le corresponde **siempre** el mismo número aleatorio, luego si inicializas la semilla con el mismo número dos veces obtendrás la misma secuencia de números aleatorios dos veces.

Por otro lado, a partir de C++11 ya tenemos a nuestra disposición una librería específica de C++ para tratar con números aleatorios. Esta librería, además de ser más práctica, ofrece números aleatorios con más garantias:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd; // Generador aleatorio: es lento, lo utilizamos para inicializar otro generador más ligero
std::mt19937 mt(rd()); // Generador más ligero, utilizaremos este en adelante
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6); // Queremos números en el rango [1, 6]

int dado1 = dist(mt);
int dado2 = dist(mt);
```

C++11 es el estándar que vio la luz allá por el 2011, así que salvo que utilices un compilador antediluviano es de esperar que reconozca éste estándar.

Por otro lado, ya siendo un poco pijos, realizas la suma de los dados unas 6 veces... es preferible *gastar* una variable para calcular la suma:

```
int total = dado1+dado2;
cout<<"La suma de los dados es: ["<<total<<"]"<<endl;
// ...
```

Y, finalmente, a mi modo de ver, te faltaría una opción para salir del bucle infinito que tienes sin necesidad de matar el programa...